# Solr: Is it possible to extract fields with regex in Query

Tags: solr

I am new in **Solr** and I come from Splunk. I just want to know if it's posisble to extract fields in query time. For example. I have this stream Query:

```
search(A3secLinuxLogs,fq=_time:[NOW-1DAY TO NOW] AND log:Accepted,fl="_time,hostname,raw_log,service_name,pid",sort=_time desc,rows=1000)
```

I get a result like this:

```
 {
    "hostname": [
      "sa3secessuperset01"
    ],
    "pid": [
      27942
    ],
    "raw_log": [
      "Jul 16 16:17:21 sa3secessuperset01 sshd[27942]: Accepted publickey for debian from 10.0.9.3 port 40954 ssh2: ED25519 SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ],
    "_time": [
      "2021-07-16T16:17:21Z"
    ],
    "service_name": [
      "sshd[27942]"
    ]
  },
```

I want from "raw_log" to extract the source ip with a regex like this

```
from:(?<src_ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)
```

Maybe something like this:

```
select(
search(A3secLinuxLogs,fq=_time:[NOW-1DAY TO NOW] AND log:Accepted,fl="_time,hostname,raw_log,service_name,pid",sort=_time desc,rows=1000),
hostname,
raw_log,
service_name,
pid,
regextract("raw_log","from:(?<src_ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)"))
```

At the moment I use Spark to achieve the same but I don't know if there is a way to do it in Solr directly.

I also tried to achieve the same in "index time" editing the schema using tokenizers and [filters](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/about-filters.html) but I get something like this:

```
 {
    "hostname": [
      "sa3secessuperset01"
    ],
    "pid": [
      27942
    ],
    "raw_log": [
      "Jul 16 16:17:21 sa3secessuperset01 sshd[27942]: Accepted publickey for debian from 10.0.9.3 port 40954 ssh2: ED25519 SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ],
    "_time": [
      "2021-07-16T16:17:21Z"
    ],
    "service_name": [
      "sshd[27942]"
    ],
    "src_ip": [
      "Jul 16 16:17:21 sa3secessuperset01 sshd[27942]: Accepted publickey for debian from 10.0.9.3 port 40954 ssh2: ED25519 SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ],
  },
```

And I want something like this:

```
{
    "hostname": [
      "sa3secessuperset01"
    ],
    "pid": [
      27942
    ],
    "raw_log": [
      "Jul 16 16:17:21 sa3secessuperset01 sshd[27942]: Accepted publickey for debian from 10.0.9.3 port 40954 ssh2: ED25519 SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ],
    "_time": [
      "2021-07-16T16:17:21Z"
    ],
    "service_name": [
      "sshd[27942]"
    ],
    "src_ip": [
      "10.0.9.3"
    ],
  },
```

I have to say the **Analysis works OK**, but the data "indexed" does not look as I want.

Basically I just want to know if there is a way to achieve what I want, I would rather to do regex in query but if it isn't possible I would like to know how to get the result with tokenizers and filters.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might have to use a Regular Expression Pattern Tokenizer:

https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/tokenizers.html#regular-expression-pattern-tokenizer

and adapt the expression for the "src_ip" field

For instance:

```
<fieldType name="extract_ip" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
          <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="(a-zA-Z0-9\s)* (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+) (a-zA-Z0-9\s)*" group="2" />
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Will mean to index only the IP. See the results here:

[image]

Comment: Hello, firstable thanks for your kindly reply. I tried what you suggested but when I copy the field "raw_log" to "src_ip" it copies the same content. When I do the analysis it works OK though but I want the copied field with the src_ip, no with the raw log content. I hope I could explain myself better.

Comment: Hello, I understand that you would like to have the IP as the "stored" value and not only as the "indexed" value. My solution would help only with the "indexed" value. I update my answer to contain all the details.

Comment: Hello again. I did that and I made clear that in the "Analysis" section everything works fine. But if you copy the field "raw_log" into "src_ip" in the query section it will show the "raw_log" content, of course I can do facet queries over "src_ip" but I don't know if the filter applies over the copied field or it's a solr bug.

Comment: Hello, it is correct, because: "Faceting is the arrangement of search results into categories based on indexed terms." (according to https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/faceting.html). Faceting over src_ip will only take into consideration what was indexed for that field, and that is the ip. What you see displayed when you search is the "stored" part, which contains the entire string.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply again. I guess Solr is more Schema on write approach: 

https://www.elastic.co/blog/schema-on-write-vs-schema-on-read

So I guess, I have to process before sending logs to Solr. Thanks for your reply again and I will accept your answer.